# What is the difference between Vec<f32> and &[f32]?

Tags: rust

[This answer](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/there-is-any-performance-difference-between-vec-f32-and-f32/72707/3) says: `&Vec<f32>` is **a pointer to a pointer** to `[f32]`,

Therefore, if I remove the `&`, make it `Vec<f32>`, meaning now it is **a pointer to [f32]**, then it is the same as `&[f32]`, is that correct?

If yes, then should I always prefer one over the other? Or can they be used interchangeably?

Thanks!

Comment: I feel more context from that quote is warranted - *"A `Vec<f32>` stores a pointer to the memory it manages, which is a sort of `[f32]`... Therefore, `&Vec<f32>` is a pointer to a pointer to `[f32]` — meaning that accessing the items in it requires the CPU to dereference two pointers, one after the other."* - the first sentence contains the nuance that `Vec` is not *literally* a pointer, it *has* a pointer.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40006220/5397009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This answer says: `&Vec<f32>` is a pointer to a pointer to `[f32]`,

As [@kmdreko points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77978243/what-is-the-difference-between-vecf32-and-f32#comment137471050_77978243), the context is important. It is more accurate to say that `Vec` (the struct) contains a pointer to a contiguous array of data. It also exposes a dynamic array interface, so methods like `push` will re-allocate the array as needed.

> Therefore, if I remove the `&`, make it `Vec<f32>`, meaning now it is a pointer to `[f32]`, then it is the same as `&[f32]`, is that correct?

This feels like weird "math" done on the types. By removing the `&` you get the owned vector, which indeed still contains the reference to the array of data. However, `&Vec<f32>` is a shared reference, whereas `Vec<f32>` is owned, so it is slightly more accurate to say that you have a `&mut [f32]`.

(All of this is somewhat hand-wavey, because [as you can see](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#62), `Vec<T>` contains `RawVec<T>`, which itself contains a `Unique<T>`, which is a raw non-null pointer.)

> If yes, then should I always prefer one over the other? Or can they be used interchangeably?

It's probably best to focus on the capabilities the different types give you:

- `Vec<f32>` - the vector is owned, so you either move it somewhere else, or the data is de-allocated when the vector is dropped. You can read from and write to the vector, and you know *that* it is a vector (and not just a slice of floats).
- `&mut Vec<f32>` - the vector is not owned, but you have a mutable reference to it. This is the same as the previous, but when the reference is dropped, the vector still exists where it was borrowed from.
- `&Vec<f32>` - not owned, shared reference. You can only read from this, but you still know that it is a vector. So you can still use methods that only exist on `Vec` and not on slices: for example, you can check the [capacity](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.capacity) of the vector.
- `&[f32]` - same as previous, but now it is just a slice of floats. It might not have come from a vector, so you cannot check the capacity.

In general, `&Vec<f32>` is not terribly useful, since almost everything you can do with it, you can also do with `&[f32]`. Furthermore, a slice of floats can come from other sources, such as an array.

When writing APIs, it is good practice to only impose as many restrictions as needed. So, functions which take a `&[f32]` seem more idiomatic than ones which take a `&Vec<f32>`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I didn't notice that `Vec` is actually a `struct`.